# iOS Core Data maintain order by attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data

I use Core Data with an Entity `People` with some attributes like a NSString `name`, a NSDate`birth_date`... What is the best way to maintain  `People` ordered by `birth_date` in Core Data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the Core Data store are not ordered. But when you *fetch* objects you can
add a *sort descriptor*  to the fetch request to get the returned
objects in a specified order. Example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"People"];
NSSortDescriptor sortByBirthDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"birth_date"
         ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortByBirthDate]];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's what I have done for now but I don't think that is an optimal solution... What if I have a lot of 'People'?

Comment: @Sierpinski: But you can't enforce an ordering on the rows in the SQLite store file. - Do you really have a performance problem? There are parameters like "fetchBatchSize" that might help. You can also add an *index* on an attribute.